# Convert 64-bits floating-point format string to floating-point number

Tags: python

I have a bunch of 64-bit floating-point-format strings, and I have to convert them into floating-point numbers. I know what the format looks like, but I’m wondering whether there’s a *built-in* function can fulfill this job directly, as in:

```
convertToFloat(C06FCA5E35000000) --> -254.324 
convertToFloat(405F7D70A4000000) --> +125.96
```

I know how to convert these bit patterns to numbers manually, but it needs a lot of bit shifting. Is there a better way?

I modified 'C06FCA5E35000000' to '\xC0\x6F\xCA\x5E\x35\x00\x00\x00', and stored it to myString.

```
>>>print (myString)
\xC0\x6F\xCA\x5E\x35\x00\x00\x00
>>>d = struct.unpack('>d', myString)
       d = struct.unpack('>d', myString)
 struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

Why did it happened?

I didn't use binascii.a2b_hex or binascii.b2a_hex, beacuse it converts 'A' to '41' or '41' to 'A'. Both are not what I want. Right?

```
>>>print len('\xC0\x6F\xCA\x5E\x35\x00\x00\x00')
8
>>>print len(myString)
32
```

Now I know why it happened, but I still don't know how to solve the situation.

Comment: Does your string look like `'C06FCA5E35000000'` or like `'\xc0\x6f\xca\x5e\x35\x00\x00\x00'`? It's not clear whether you're talking about a string whose raw bit pattern encodes the floating-point number or a string containing hexadecimal text representing the floating-point number's bit pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `struct.unpack`. `>d` is a big-endian double; see `help(struct)` for more!

```
import struct

d, = struct.unpack('>d', b'\xc0\x6f\xca\x5e\x35\x00\x00\x00')

print(d)
# -254.32399988174438
```

If your string is really `'C06FCA5E35000000'`, you can convert it first into bytes using [`binascii.a2b_hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex).

Comment: nice answer +1 :) I was pretty stumped by this one

Comment: It looks to me like the OP has a string with literal hex digits in it. `'C06FCA5E35000000'` instead of `b'\xc0\x6f\xca\x5e\x35\x00\x00\x00'`.

Comment: I modified string 'C06FCA5E35000000' to '\xc0\x6f\xca\x5e\x35\x00\x00\x00', and stored it to string.       >>>print string                                                                   \xc0\x6f\xca\x5e\x35\x00\x00\x00                                        >>>d = struct.unpack('>d', string)                                   struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8         why did it happened?

Comment: I didn't use binascii.a2b_hex. Because this function convert '42' to 'B', and binascii.b2a_hex converts 'B' to '42'. Both of them are not what I want. Right?

Comment: @LiarLai: `\xc0` isn’t the literal content of the string; it only works in string literals and produces the byte C0. You have to use `binascii.a2b_hex`, but not just by itself; it’s something you do before unpacking. So `d, = struct.unpack('>d', binascii.a2b_hex(string))`, where `string` is `'C06FCA5E35000000'` again.